# Python and Neo4j first 10 Elements

Tags: python, neo4j

Is it Possible to select first 10 entries of Neo4j graph just like we do in a Document oriented Database?

Answer (score 1):

When using a Cypher query, you can use the [`LIMIT`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#query-limit) [clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/3.0/) to complement `RETURN`:

```
MATCH (n:SomeLabel)
RETURN n
LIMIT 10
```